# use of nop(0xc3=ret) in return oriented programming

Tags: security, x86, buffer-overflow, exploit

I am failing to see any use of nop's in rop why do people use them? I have seen some examples of rop gadget chains like (G2,G3,G4 are some gadgets)

```
nop(return gadget)-(G2)-(G3)-somedata-(G4)---nop(return gadget)---
```

What is the use of using nop at the start or somewhere in the middle?

Comment: Lol someone please answer this. Thank you.

Comment: Do people do that?  Normally NOPs are useful if you aren't sure of the exact address, e.g. for code injection into a stack buffer rather than ROP.  So if RIP points to an earlier NOP, execution will still fall through to the code you wanted.